# Algorithm that transforms flat object shape in bitmap to collection of Vectors in 2D Coord System

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, graphics

I currently try to figure out an algorithm that would transform a bitmap like this :

[image]

To collection of vectors in two-dimensional coordinate system. And unfortunately, i figured out nothing . Have anyone heard about an algorithm that solves this problem ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, hence the comment, but did you take a look at the Hough Transform Algorithm? It is usually pretty good as finding shapes.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means the "best" method but I tried this a while back and it worked fairly well. The only thing I would request is that the shapes be filled in.

What I did was to treat the image as a density field and apply the [marching squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) algorithm to it. This of course generated far too many vertices (even when not sampling at native rez), so I did some very primitive decimation: removing vertices where the adjacent edges are nearly straight (by removing I mean replace vertex + 2 edges with a single edge). After iterating the decimation a few times I had a low vertex vector representation.

Improvements might involve turning the input into a signed distance field to improve marching squares or sampling along the square edges to find intersections with the original image (jump from black to white is an intersection).

For a real algorithm you'd want to search for "vectorizing".